# Notepad ++: How to group correclty so replacement works

Tags: windows, notepad++

I was given the replacement "\n\1=\2". My job is to create a search pattern so that the replacement is successful.

My data goes like this:

```
There are Spanish translations for some names like Mary (Maria), John (Juan), Michael (Miguel) and Joseph (Jose).
```

My goal is to make it look like this:

```
There are Spanish translations for some names like 
Mary = Maria
John = Juan
Michael = Miguel
Joseph = Jose.
```

The search I had so far was "are.|,.|\and. + (^[a-z]\S)+(.*\S)". Even if the first part of the search works, it is not grouping correctly for when replacement comes. I don't know what to change from the search or how it should be changed to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\w+)\h+\((\w+)\)\h*(?:,|and)?\h*(\.)?`
- Replace with: `\n$1 = $2$3`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(\w+)       # group 1, 1 or more word characters, English name
\h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
\(          # openning parenthesis
(\w+)       # group 2, 1 or more word characters, the Spanish name
\)          # closing parenthesis
\h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
(?:         # non capture group
    ,       # a comma
  |         # OR
    and     # literally and
)?          # end group, optional
\h*         # 0 or mor horizontal spaces
(\.)?       # group 3, a dot, optional
```

**Replacement:**

```
\n          # linefeed, you can use \r\n for windows linebreak
$1          # content of group 1
 =          # space, equal sign, space
$2          # content of group 2
$3          # content of group 3
```

**Result for given example:**

```
There are Spanish translations for some names like 
Mary = Maria
John = Juan
Michael = Miguel
Joseph = Jose.
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I’m not specifically familiar
with the search-and-replace capability of Notepad++,
but Unix’s `sed` is pretty similar.

I believe that there’s no way you can get the *exact* result that you want
with the *exact* replacement string you showed,
because you want spaces before the Spanish names ( `Maria`,  `Juan`, etc.),
but there are no such spaces present in the input text. 
You’ll need to add at least one space to the replacement string.

The `-r` option tells `sed` to use “extended regular expressions”. 
We don’t absolutely need that option, but

- `sed` (by default) uses `(` and `)` to match parentheses,
  and `\(…\)` to capture a group, while
- `sed -r` uses `\(` and `\)` to match literal parentheses,
  and `(…)` to capture a group.

You seem to be expecting to be able to use `(…)` to capture a group,
so I’ll do this with `-r`.

You can do this is a single substitution in `sed` with

```
sed -r 's/\s([A-Za-z]*)\s\(([A-Za-z]*)\)(,| and)*/\n\1 = \2/g'
```

That can be broken down into

```
sed -r 's/   \s   ([A-Za-z]*)   \s   \(   ([A-Za-z]*)   \)   (,| and)?   /   \n\1 = \2   /g'
```

- `s/` — begin a substitute command.
- `\s` — a space. 
  In `sed`, you can use actual space characters;
  I suspect that that’s true for Notepad++ as well. 
  In `sed` you can also use `[[:space:]]`. 
  Of course a space matches just a space,
  but `\s` and `[[:space:]]` match space or tab.
- `([A-Za-z]*)` — a capture group of any number of letters
  (upper or lower case), to match the English version of the name. 
  In `sed` you can also use `[[:alpha:]]`
  (or `[[:upper:]]` or `[[:lower:]]`, as desired).
- `\s` — another space.
- `\(` — a literal left parenthesis
  (the one before the Spanish version of the name).
- `([A-Za-z]*)` — same as above — a capture group of any number of letters
  (upper or lower case), to match the Spanish version of the name.
- `\)` — a literal right parenthesis
  (the one after the Spanish version of the name).
- `(,| and)?` — a group that matches `,` ***or***  `and`, zero or one time. 
  This matches the stuff that comes between
  the right parenthesis after the Spanish version of the name,
  and the next English-version name. 
  We need to be able to handle zero occurrences of this group
  because we need to match `Joseph (Jose)`,
  even though there’s not comma or “`and`” after it.
  Note that we could use `\sand` instead of  `and`;
  I believe that  `and` is much more readable. 
  Also note that we could use `*` (zero or more, with no limit)
  instead of `?`.
- `/` — end of search string; beginning of replacement string.
- `\n\1 = \2` — your replacement string
  (newline, the first capture group,  `=` , and the second capture group). 
  As mentioned earlier, I have added spaces before and after the `=`.
- `/g` — end of command. 
  The `g` stands for “global” and specifies that the substitution
  should be performed as many times as possible (the default is once per line).

So the Notepad++ command is probably very similar.